# Jquery on selecting id issue

Tags: jquery

Can you let me know what is the problem with my code. I have given the code for all the sections belowie; the HTML/CSS & JQuery

When I click my go veg button the class fish should hide.

CSS file

```
div{
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 height:245px;
 text-align:left;
 border: solid #000 3px;
}
```

html file

```
<html>
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/styles/my_style.css"   />
    <script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/scripts/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/scripts/my_scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

<body>
<div class="topper">
    <h2>Our Menu</h2>
      <div class="buttons"><button type="submit" value="vegon">Go Vegetarian</button></div>
      <div class="buttons"><button type="submit" value="restoreme">Restore Menu</button></div>
</div>
<div class="middle">
<li>Thai-style Halibut
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li                 >coconut milk</li>
  <li class="fish"    >pan-fried halibut</li>
  <li                 >lemongrass broth</li>
  <li                 >vegetables</li>
  <li                 >Thai spices </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Braised Delight
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="meat"    >lamb shoulder</li>
  <li                 >cippolini onions</li>
  <li                 >carrots</li>
  <li                 >baby turnip</li>
  <li                 >braising jus</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>House Grilled Panini
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="meat"    >prosciutto</li>
  <li                 >provolone</li>
  <li                 >avocado</li>
  <li                 >cherry tomatoes</li>
  <li                 >sourdough roll</li>
  <li                 >shoestring fries </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>House Slider
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li                 >eggplant</li>
  <li                 >zucchini</li>
  <li class="hamburger">hamburger</li>
  <li                 >balsamic vinegar</li>
  <li                 >onion</li>
  <li                 >carrots</li>
  <li                 >multigrain roll</li>
  <li                 >goat cheese</li>
 </ul>
</li>   <li>Frittata
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="meat"    >eggs</li>
  <li                 >Asiago cheese</li>
  <li                 >potatoes </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Coconut Soup
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li                 >coconut milk</li>
  <li class="meat"    >chicken</li>
  <li                 >vegetable broth</li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Soup Du Jour
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li class="meat"    >grilled steak</li>
  <li                 >mushrooms</li>
  <li                 >vegetables</li>
  <li                 >vegetable broth </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Hot and Sour Soup
 <ul class="menu_list">
  <li                 >roasted pork</li>
  <li                 >carrots</li>
  <li                 >Chinese mushrooms</li>
  <li                 >chili</li>
  <li                 >vegetable broth </li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li>Avocado Rolls
  <ul class="menu_list">
  <li                 >avocado</li>
  <li                 >whole chiles</li>
  <li                 >sweet red peppers</li>
  <li                 >ginger sauce</li>
 </ul>
</li>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".buttons").click(function(){
    $("li.fish").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: Seems to work for me, http://jsfiddle.net/EAcEC/

Comment: I suspect there will be a 'call to undefined function $' in the console.

Comment: `<script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/scripts/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>`  You can't do this, you can't load a JavaScript file from your local machine into a website (unless this page is also running on your local machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing wrong every thing is fine.
just replace following line from head

```
<script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/scripts/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to [work](http://jsfiddle.net/EG242/), but in any case pinpoint the selection to the buttons not the containers.

```
$(".buttons button").click(function(){
    $("li.fish").hide();
});
```

Judging by your code, where you are loading scripts like

```
<script src="file://c:/jquery/chapter-2/begin/scripts/jquery.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Make is the path is correct and is loaded. Further, It will be better if you relative path rather than absolutes.

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The snippet above signifies, there is a folder with jQuery script, on the same base path as the active file.

Comment: Event will propagate to the container so what he has should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. I suspect you probably aren't having jQuery loaded. Try swapping out your local reference to the Google CDN file:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

You'll also have to make sure your local js files are loaded as well. You appear to be working through some book examples, so consider using relative paths to your resources:

If your webpage is currently in `c:/jQuery/chapter-2/`, use the following for your file references:

```
<script src="begin/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```